# How to center an image between the containers?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the image responsive and keep it in between the containers left and right.

I have tried putting it all into another container and it doesn’t work.

I know it sounds basic but it really is not.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 800px;
  float: right;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<img src="paintingOg.gif" style="width:50%">
```

Comment: please check this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp

Comment: @AlexCiu there is a basic problem with this it always disappears when you shrink your browser. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this way? Is it (close to) what you need? Please check *responsiveness* too.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 800px;
  float: right;
}

.center {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="center">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?gravity=west">
</div>
```

Comment: @scriver I have replaced `overflow: hidden;` with `overflow: auto;`, because it makes the answer a lot more useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need containers to center something.
It's better to use 1 container that contains everything.
If you want to center your image into a div just use this code:

```
<div align="center">
    <image src="whatever.png"/>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 800px;
  float: right;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div align="center">
<img src="paintingOg.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: `align` is an obsolete attribute and should not be used. There are significantly better ways of centering.

Comment: @Paulie_D works just fine so I'll just use it. If you have a better solution please post it cause I'm courious about discovering new ways of doing things